How can I get Rows from a specific Data Extension and add them to another one using SSJS?
I want to insert the rows from an existing data extension with the same column structure into another one using SSJS within Automation-Studio. I am using SSJS because I want to add them dynamically, where SQL cannot be a solution because you have to select the target Data-Extension manually.
So first I tried to select the DataExtension and add its rows into another DataExtension using the following code:
    <script runat="server">
    
    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    var submitsDe = DataExtension.Init("xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxx")
    var data = submitsDe.Rows.Retrieve(); // Get all rows from source DE as Array
    var anotherDe = DataExtension.Init("another_de")
    anotherDe.Rows.Add(data) // This should work because Add() function also accepts array of objects source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsAdd.html
    </script>

I added this script to my data automation and ran it and it also says that it ran successfully, but the new data extension did not add any new rows. I have also tried to debug the code by testing it within a cloud page to see if I really get an array of objects with all the record entries from the "submitsDe" table.
So the code is executed but I don't see any result. Is there any other way to debug the code if there is no other solution?
Thank you in advance!

There could be a few possible reasons:

You need to initialize the DEs using their external keys. Make sure all DEs are initialized by their external key.

These two DEs might not have the same structure, even if they seem similar. I would suggest creating a new DE to replace the second one for testing. Use the "create from existing" method to set up the test DE.

Primary key violation. If your DE has a primary key and more than one column is designated as the primary key, you may encounter a violation if there's already a record with the same key.


You can wrap your code in try-catch statements to capture exceptions, but this may not provide much useful information.
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");
try{

// Your Code

} catch (ex){
    Write(Stringify(ex));
}
</script>


Please take the time to read the official documentation on these two functions.  The examples aren't terrible and you'll find the proper parameters spelled out.

SSJS Data Extension Retrieve
SSJS Data Extension Add

You'll need to assign a variable for the Add function results, since it returns the number of rows inserted.
I'd suggest testing in a CloudPage with debug flag along with a try/catch as @Duc Le suggested.  Once it's working, set debug to false to disable the output.
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
   
 Platform.Load("core", "1");

 var debug = true;

 try {

   var de1 = DataExtension.Init("ExampleMaster");
  
   //var filter = {Property:"SubscriberKey",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"8b7df23e-dca3-4b69-be10-f07e43fd730d"};
   var filter;  
   // https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsRetrieve.html 
   // limited to 2500 results
  
   var de1Results = de1.Rows.Retrieve(filter);

   if (debug) {
     Write("<hr>de1Results: " + Stringify(de1Results))
   }

   var de2 = DataExtension.Init("ExampleMasterCopy")

   // https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_dataExtensionAdd.html
   try {

     var de2Results = de2.Rows.Add(de1Results) 

     if (debug) {
       Write("<hr>de2Results: " + de2Results)
     }


   } catch (e2) {

     if (debug) {
       Write("<hr>e2: " + Stringify(e2))
     }

   }

 } catch (e) {

     if (debug) {
       Write("<hr>e: " + Stringify(e))
     }

 }

</script>

Results:

